# Error : Domain contained invalid characters

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, dns, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing smart TV application using Facebook Javascript SDK.

I want to implement function which is uploading message on my feed, so I use FB.api like this :

```
function FacebookUpload(msg){
var path = '/me/feed'; 
FB.api(path, 'Post', { message: msg, access_token: token}, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert("error");
     } else {
        alert("successful with id [" + response.id + "]");
     }
});
}
```

It works well in PC, but doesn't work in smart TV.
The error message is like this.

File:           http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
Line No:        62
Error Detail:   Error: Domain contained invalid characters.

Why does this message occur and how do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you perhaps running this on a domain with underscores? This is not allowed per any of the specs defining the structure of valid URL's.
Please add environmental information to the question, such as what `location`, `location.host` etc resolves to.

Comment: Location is 'file://D/Samsung/Samsung TV SDK(3.5.0)/apps/myapp/index.html?country=US&language=1&lang=en&modelid=SDK&server=development&firmware=T-SPHAKRC-1000&remocon=4_35_259_12&area=USA'. This is executed by emulator and will be excuted by local system in TV. Location.host is D.

Comment: The JS SDK does not support being used over the file: protocol as there is no defined security model for file: > http/https, which is required for almost all use.